# Adding a menu item to Windows Explorer right click context menu in java

Tags: java, c++, windows

I am developing an application in which I want to add a menu item to context menu which appears when we right click one or more file or folders in Windows Explorer. By selecting multiple files or folder and clicking my item in context menu it should send the path of all the files and folders to my application executable for further processing. Please provide me some code for this if possible in Java or C++.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  PLease read the help section http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  on how to ask a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term for this kind of thing is Shell Extension.

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144067%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN is perhaps a reasonable starting point. Beyond that you now have the proper term so you can google for guides and examples.